# Redirect users based on username (LDAP)

Tags: php, ldap

We have an apache 2.2 install with this config on an Ubuntu 12.04:

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Please provide USERNAME AND PASSWORD!"
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AuthLDAPURL "ldap://foo.com/c=uk,ou=bar,o=foo.com?mail"
            Require valid-user
            Require ldap-attribute dept=4F4623
            Require ldap-attribute emailAddress=someone@somewhere.com
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel info
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working great with LDAP auth! We have ldap-utils, php5, apache2.2-common.

#### Question:

How can we create a page, so for example:

```
somedomain.com/selectorpage.html
```

redirects the logged in user to another page based on their username?

So if XY user visits the "selectorpage.html", then it will be redirected immediately to page XY.html. If AB user visits the "selectorpage.html", then it will be redirected immediately to page AB.html. Or are there any apache redirects for this?

Comment: Only an idea, I've not tried this: Set the `REMOTE_USER` variable to the logged-in user ([AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute) could help), and then use `mod_rewrite` to redirect: Use a condition `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.*)` to get the user name, and redirect using a backreferencing rewrite-rule after that: `RewriteRule .* /%1.html`, where %1 will be replaced with the username.

Answer (score 4):

combining [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239069/how-do-i-retrieve-the-user-information-of-a-user-authenticated-with-apaches-mod) with your information, Id suggest you use a php page, instead of an html page in place of selector page.html, and using

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

inside the selector_page.php with either:

```
switch($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']){
    case "user_a":
        $url = "xy.html";
        break;
    ......
    case "user_n":
        $url = "nn.html";
        break;
    default:
        $url = "ab.html";
        break;
}
header("location: $url");
```

or similar

( you might need to do a mod_rewrite rule to change the selectorpage.html to selectorpage.php if its an external link and not under your control, but it would be better to change the link to point to the php page if its not )

Comment: if you have 100 users do you need add 100 urls and cases?